# Setting the default of a database Field to the value of another field in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

```
db.define_table('mytable',
    Field('start_number', 'double', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('current_number', 'double', default=mytable.start_number, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))
```

When something happens on the website, `current_number` can be changed to something else, but will always start with the default value of `start_number` (ie, when the entry is created). Each entry has a different `start_number`.

I keep getting an error saying that `mytable` can't be found, probably because it hasn't been fully defined yet. Is it still possible to set the default value of `current_number` to `start_number`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If inserts will always be done via form submissions, you could do:

```
Field('current_number', 'double', default=request.post_vars.start_number, ...)
```

Another option is to make it a computed field:

```
Field('current_number', 'double', compute=lambda r: r.start_number, ...)
```

However, by default, computed fields are not shown in forms created with `SQLFORM`, so if you want to display the field in an update form, you will have to explicitly specify the fields to show on the form or temporarily set the field's "compute" attribute to None.

Comment: I tried this like this http://pastebin.com/FQxvZrs1, but it didn't work. Using default= doesn't define the field on INSERT, and COMPUTE= redefines it also on INSERT, which I prefer not to do.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking - maybe open up a new question and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Anthony, your answer here was useful https://groups.google.com/d/msg/web2py/vMe41spAnCY/CaBeXt3OBgAJ