# web2py - how to set the value of field2 to the value of field1

Tags: python, web2py, default-value

I am new to web2py and I am trying to add extra fields to auth_user and I am trying to set the default value of 'mentor' to be the value entered for 'referrer' as shown in code below but it is not working. No data is appended when the record is created. The 'mentor' can change at a later stage but the default is to be set to the 'referrer'. What am I doing wrong? Please advice.

```
from gluon.tools import Auth, Crud, Service, PluginManager, prettydate
auth = Auth(db)
crud, service, plugins = Crud(db), Service(), PluginManager()
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']=[
   Field('gender', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Female', 'Male'])),
   Field('birthday', type='date'),
   Field('country'),
   Field('city'),
   Field('referrer', default = 'admin'),
   Field('mentor', default=request.post_vars.referrer)]
```

Comment: See: [Setting the default of a database Field to the value of another field in web2py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280220/setting-the-default-of-a-database-field-to-the-value-of-another-field-in-web2py)

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck doing

```
def get_default_mentor():
    return request.post_vars.referrer
```

and

```
default=get_default_mentor()
```

It is my experience that it's best to set the default field to a function that gets the default value, when the default value can change.